# How to know the file position in Dockers using Node-RED's Write file node?

Tags: docker, node-red

I'm trying to make an operating report of molding cabinets. I use Node-RED to get data like temperature and time and send them to the operator. I managed to create a UI that allow the operator to see how the report will be. I use pdfmake node and write file node  to create the report but the problem is where it is saved. I know it's in Docker but I don't know where exactly the file went.

Do I need to create a place where it saves or is there already a place where it saves ?

(I'm using Node-RED v2.1.4 and I'm on Windows)

I used the read file to see if I can read what i write in the file is saved and It is.

Answer (score 1):

You should use full paths in the file nodes so you can place it explicitly where you want it. e.g. `/data/foo.pdf`

You should also probably place the file in `/data` because hopefully you already have a volume mounted here to persist your flows across a container restart.

P.S. Node-RED 2.1.4 is WAY OUT of support, you should upgrade to at 3.0.2 (or hopefully to 3.1.0 when it ships soon)